# Pytorch RNN data from three different csv. Python 3

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

i need to train a RNN on pythorch on features vectors taken from 3 different frames of the same object. The features dimensions are alway the same.

I have a csv for first frames, csv for seconds frames, csv for third one.

Need to take the same raw from different csvs in order to get the features about the specific frame. 
(raw 1 in csv1 is frame 1 of object x, raw 1 in csv2 is frame 2 of object x, raw 1 in csv3 is frame 3 of object x)

I need to create a RNN that at state t0, t1, t2 take frame 1 features, frame 2 features and frame 3.

I saw character examples and time prediction ones where for each state are fed a single character of a world or a single time value of the dataset.

How can I organize the training in order to take a whole features vector to train that state, then the second feature and so on?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly (your question is not very specific), but why not just using padding for this?

Comment: @blue-phoenox could you be more specific? I honestly don't know what you're talking about..

Comment: If your question is about *what I assume it is about* - you can use padding to solve your problem. If not, I don't understand what you are asking. Then you should try to be *more specific* in your question in order to get proper help, show what you have already done, post some examples!